# I cannot write less and greater symbol. How can ı write?

Tags: equations

how can ı write this symbol. If you help me this problem thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: In the future answers to [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) may help if you are looking for a particular symbol

Comment: I’m more interested in how you managed to input a small caps “I” in the title of this question?

Comment: @Gaussler The character is "U+0131 ı LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I". At a guess, probably a "tapo"/typo/auto-complete action when using a keyboard overlay or input method that presents a list of glyphs to choose from: `I i Ì ì Í í Î î Ï ï Ĩ ĩ Ī ī Ĭ ĭ Į į İ ı` etc. Easy to do. I i Ì ì Í í Î î Ï ï Ĩ ĩ Ī ī Ĭ ĭ Į į İ ı

Comment: @Cicada Yes, sure, I can also look up unicode characters if I have to. But this is not something I just end up accidentally typing instead of an “I”.

Comment: @Gaussler . No lookup. I did it just then - long-press `i` on the alpha keyboard, then slide to what looked like `I` but was in fact dotless-i: so a "slide-o", not a "tap-o" or typo. These phone screens are too small. :) New txtng spelling. Handy, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here there is the example of your image using a macro named `\hupdown`: the symbol is `\gtrless`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\hupdown[1]{\mathop{\operatorname{#1}}} 

\begin{document}
\[\hupdown{\scriptstyle \gtrless}_{\mathcal{H}_0}^{\mathcal{H}_1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you prefer you can choose this MWE reducing the size of the symbol with `\scriptscriptstyle`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\hupdown[1]{\mathop{\operatorname{#1}}} 

\begin{document}
\[\hupdown{ \gtrless}_{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{H}_0}^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{H}_1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Addendum after a deleted answer that it is an edit on the question of the user.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\newcommand\hupdown[1]{\mathop{\operatorname{#1}}} 
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\txsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\[\mathbb{T}_{i}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i})=\sum_{n=1}^{N}{|\boldsymbol{y}_{i}}[n]{{|}^{2}}\hupdown{ \gtrless}_{\scriptscriptstyle\pazocal{H}_0}^{\scriptscriptstyle\pazocal{H}_1}\lambda\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum of the 2021/09/08**.
Another alternative given from @egreg in this question here [Underset and Overset Together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614655/underset-and-overset-together) is to use the command `\overunderset{....}{....}{....}` without a macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \overunderset command
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[bb = boondox]{mathalfa}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsCM}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\txsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbolsCM}{"50}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\[\mathbb{T}_{i}(\boldsymbol{y}_{i})=\sum_{n=1}^{N}{|\boldsymbol{y}_{i}}[n]{{|}^{2}}\overunderset{\pazocal{H}_0}{\pazocal{H}_1}{\gtrless}\lambda\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You write about the second MWE "you can choose this MWE **reducing** the size of the symbol", but when I look at the posted images the `hupdown` symbol appears larger (at least, proportinally compared to the the H_1 and H_0) in the second image posted.  Did you accidentally get the images swapped around?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Jarak I have done a mistake. :-(

Comment: @Jarak I was falling asleep. Can you please see if this is now correct?

Comment: Hmmm, I just ran both of your MWEs (recent MikTeX installation, using pdflatex), and the second one definitely comes out with a larger symbol than the first one.  Looking more closely at them, though, I realise that I was indeed misunderstanding:  The second MWE actually adjust the H_1 and H_0, not the middle symbol.  Anyway, you've answered the question well, probably best just to leave it until you feel more awake :)