# Underset and Overset Together

Tags: overset

I would like to use `\overset` and `\underset` together on this formula but it gives me an error. As soon as I change the equality sign (=) and use max instead it is fixed. Can you help me with that?

```
\[
 \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{2x}}

 \overset{\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]}{\underset{\mathrm{H}}{=}}

 \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x}{2}}={\frac{1}{2}}
\]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have blank lines in math displays. Also `amsmath` offers `\overunderset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
 \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{2x}}
 \overunderset{\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]}{\mathrm{H}}{=}
 \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{e^x}{2}}={\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your code did fine even though my problem was \usepackage{breqn} which prevented my code to compile. but your code is fine with that thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can't have empty (blank) lines inside a display math environment `\[`...`\]`. Remove those and your minimal code will compile.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^x - 1}{2x}}
  \overset{\left[ \frac{0}{0} \right]}{\underset{\mathrm{H}}{=}}
  \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^x}{2}} = {\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes yes my code is without blank, but funny thing was that when i compile your code with only amsmath it worked but it did not work on my .tex file. so i removed some packages one by one and '\usepackage{breqn}' was preventing the code to compile. why?!

Comment: @RoozbehRanjbar: Not sure why. Use egreg's answer instead since it seems to work with [`breqn`](//ctan.org/pkg/breqn).